# Blank screen after login ubuntu 12.10

Tags: upgrade, virtualbox, windows-8

There is literally nothing on the screen except the colorful background and the mouse.

Issue with windows 8+ Intel HD+ Sun virtual Box+ 32 Mb of Video Memory After the login nothing comes up but able to go to CLI by ctrl+alt+F1. Also i started up ssh and able to work through the CLI but UI doesnt work at all.

Do i need any specific version of the drivers for Intel HD 4000?

Comment: Check: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: Also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-virtualbox

Comment: Finally your graphical card doesn't matter if you are running in Virtual Box, Ubuntu can't use it. The Guest Additions provide all the (virtual) drivers that you need.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be with Unity and forcing to 3D.

I solved this problem following the following document:
http://blogs.operationaldynamics.com/paul/opensource/not-unifed-in-12-10-the-quickening

I did not do the last part of the document.  All I did is as follows:

1. After you login, you get an empty screen with the Ubuntu wallpaper, at this point do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>t</kbd>.  This will launch the terminal window.
2. Issue the following commands:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
   sudo apt-get -f update
   sudo apt-get -f install gdm gnome-shell gnome-tweak-tool gnome-session-fallback
   ```
3. You will be asked what Window Manager to use, make sure you select GDM.
4. Reboot, while still in the terminal window, issue the following command:

   ```
   sudo shutdown -r now
   ```

That should do it.  If you still have issues, make sure your read the web link listed above.